# About the vipassana jhana

Tags: theravada

When the mind cease and breathing appear automatically ;means the experience  of knower ?in which jhana the consciousness is expanding?

Answer (score 0):

i think "knower" is a term used by contemporary meditation teachers especially if this "knower" is used in a context outside of 5 skandhas then it might be problematic.   (tho not 100% sure, if anyone can provide pali for knower then i would look it up).  Unless "knower" from your question means vinnana, consciousness. 
according to pali texts, mind temporary ceases (while still alive) at cessation meditation level. Mind still exists even at neither perception nor non-perception level.

from what i read, consciousness expands to infinite space at non-form perception (above 4th jhana). "the sphere of infinite space perception"..

Comment: I notice in satipatthana that two distinct terms are used in connection with the different contemplations: "he knows" and "he understands". I think a disparity between the two terms is somewhat greyed-out because one can be used as a synonym for the other and visa versa. I often wonder from what they were translated from and why distinguish them as "he knows" and "he understands". There is another way to look at this: after watching the aggregates persistently, the 'knowing' faculty takes on a different form such that it cannot really be known as knowing. I guess words diverge at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Anapanassati Jhana enter the Access Concentration State when these all happen together for many sitting period continually...

1. The mindful is stronger and stronger. It could has only breath for 2-3 hours without any other objects and
2. the  light is so strong and stable at the same point of breath mark (inside nose tip normally) and
3. No any five hindrances could arise.

This is the first state we could feel the right knower in the concentration meditation before the Absorption in Concentration.

see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0eYC003WYZA&t=4s